# Best Practice: Symfony2 DataGrid

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid

I was wondering if someone can help be to point me to an example for a "Best Practice" example for a sortable, searchable datagrid in Symfony2 with the doctrine ORM.

I always see Tutorials with the implementation of some data, generating Entity and so forth, but some/all lack the code how to enable Pagination, how can the user search in multiple fields from the frontend and how to handle the ordering after a field the user chooses to.

Before some folks now think I'm stupid, of course i can make a GET Variable and just make an IF clause to ask for it but i would really appreciate a best Practice example so i know how i am supposed to handle it.

Right now I'm thinking about an open source project for a Organisation system, so i will have many Tables i have to join and many datagrids to display. I would really love to get it in a right way so i don't have to write it all over again when the community is laughing at my code...

Thank you for reading and your help.

Answer (score 2):

I use apy data grid bundle https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle

It works very well and it's very simple to use

Comment: Hello, thank you but APYDataGridBundle is a out of the box bundle. I would like to crate my own bundle or at least my own working version bcause I want some things to learn (ex. how pagination works best in symfony) and I also have some secial things in mind that APYDataGridBundle does not have.

Answer (score 1):

For your goal, you can take a look a [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html) in which you can describe by yaml, for instance, you entities relations, search operands, and you'll have a full application to do CRUD and search without much trouble. I setup my basic crud/search operations on the 20 basic entities in a day or two.

I honestly don't know how sonata is organized and if the datagrid is "extractable" or if you could use it as a service, but I believe is a good starting point.